# innerHTML nav (main content appears with nav content)

Tags: html, navigation, innerhtml, nav

First off, I've no background in html at all, just fiddling around with my little knowledge of the basic stuffs .. so, sorry if my question is stupid.

I have a problem with innerhtml while doing up my blog template; when I manage to get through with the navigation, the blog content is seen with the nav content. (You can view it at my blog [here](http://esther-tch.blogspot.sg/)) It's kind of frustrating because it feels like there's left that I've not tried. My basic code is like this:

```
<body>

<span class="nav" onMouseover="this.style.color='#ddd'" onMouseout="this.style.color='#000'" onClick="document.getElementById('main').innerHTML=document.getElementById('about').innerHTML">ABOUT</span>

<div class="content2">
    <p id="main">

        <div id="about" style="display: none;">
        Content...
        </div>

    </p>

    <blogger>....</bloger>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but i dont get the problem here. http://jsfiddle.net/8zoobzen/ working fine i think.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your problem is but I think the main thing would be that if you had multiple sections, your links would only work once (as the element you are trying to target gets deleted after the first link click).

To solve this, move the target blocks (ie the `about` element) outside the `main` element.  Also I would change the main element into a div as if any of the content within about has a `p` tag, you will end up with nested `p`s which is invalid content

```html
<div class="content2">
    <div id="main">
    </div>
    <div id="about" style="display: none;">
        Content...
    </div>
</div>
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1L0nte8/)

Comment: `<p id=main>` acts as the main "box" for the content right? (I used p because it's easier to identify actually). My problem is that the main page content is still there when I click the nav `<div id="about">`. What I wanted to do was to hide the main page content when I click on a nav.

Comment: yep, it should do.  when the links are clicked, it will populate the "main" box with the content of the div that is targeted in the onclick event

Comment: It's so weird because it works on my other blog. Hmm, I'll try to figure it out. Thanks!